# Nodatime Interval serialization with offset

Tags: c#, nodatime

Currently if I serialize Interval (using Nodatime JSON serializer) it gives me a string like below -
"2007-03-01T13:00:00Z/2008-05-11T15:30:00Z"

Is there a way to have offset information with interval as shown in the example below?

"2007-03-01T13:00:00-08:00/2008-05-11T15:30:00-08:00"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Interval` is a pair of `Instant` values.  An `Instant` is always represented in terms of UTC.

To achieve the output you requested, you'd need to have a pair of `OffsetDateTime` values.  Noda Time doesn't have any built-in type for that, but you could certainly create it yourself.  You'd also have to write a `JsonConverter` for it.